# Change the style of a button based on a condition (with KnockoutJS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

### The Goal

Change the style of a button based on a item from a list.

### The problem

I have two lists on my application: the first one is a list of available products whose has a button to add it to the Shopping Cart; the second one is a list of already added products.

When some product is already added, I want to change the "plus button" to "less button" to remove the item from the list.

Someone knows how can I do this?

### What you already have tried?

Nothing. I read the KnockoutJS documentation and I searched on the web about this question, but with no success. I do not even know where to start.

### Show me the code!

With pleasure.

My HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-small add" 
        title="Add to your cart.">
    <i class="icon-plus"></i>
</button>
```

And the JS:

```
function ProductLayoutViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.existsAtList = function () {
        console.log("Testing.");
    };
};
```

### And how about the `if` binding?

I have already tried this:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-small add" 
        title="Adicionar à lista de comparação" 
        data-bind="if: existsAtList()">
    <i class="icon-plus"></i>
</button>
```

But the console returns me this:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>
> Message: ReferenceError: existsAtList is not defined;
>
> Bindings value: if: existsAtList()

Yes! I know that the syntax is wrong — like I said: *"I do not even know where to start."*

### Why -1?

To whom negative the topic, please speak up. I'll be grateful for the constructive criticism.

Comment: Can you do a jsFiddle, or at least post your JavaScript?

Comment: Hey, @woz! I have updated my code — take a look.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3RNk7/. Are you sure all your JS files are getting included? Did you do `ko.applyBindings();` correctly?

Comment: Here it is with `alert` instead of `console.log`: http://jsfiddle.net/3RNk7/1/.

Comment: can you please post more JS code ? i think the problem is wrong BindingContext

Comment: @ebramtharwat There is no more JS.

Comment: @chiefGui then post your all code(html and js) in a jsfiddle example

Comment: @ebramtharwat I did that, and it appears to be working.

Comment: Ok, @woz and ebram, I solve the (first) problem — wasn't `if existsAtList()` but is `if ProductsLayout.existAtList()`. But now, how can I proceed? How can I change the button style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change between a plus button and a minus button, put the two buttons in spans and show/hide them appropriately:

```
<span data-bind="ifnot: existsAtList()">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-small add" 
            title="Adicionar à lista de comparação">
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
    </button>
</span>

<span data-bind="if: existsAtList()">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-small add" 
            title="Eliminar de lista de comparação">
        <i class="icon-minus"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

I demonstrated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rSD7q/

---

You can also bind to the title of the `<button>` and the class of the `<i>` element:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-small add" data-bind="attr: { title: existsAtList() ? 'Eliminar de lista de comparação' : 'Adicionar à lista de comparação' }">
    <i data-bind="attr: { class: existsAtList() ? 'icon-minus' : 'icon-plus' }"></i>
</button>
```

This could be more cumbersome if you had to bind many attributes, but both ways are perfectly valid, and neither should really cause performance issues. It's all about your preference for what is easier for you to read, write, and debug.

Here is the jsFiddle for this way: http://jsfiddle.net/PKMXT/

Comment: Oh, god! THANKS! — Just to knowledge: do you know if this is a good practice? (And thanks about the translation! Hehehe.. Was difficult to discover my idiom?)

Comment: Yes, this should be a good way to do it in knockout. I used Google Translate :)

Comment: For each product that I have on my application there will two buttons? Perhaps this is not a little *non-performatic*?

Comment: Well, you could bind to the title and the class of the `<i>` element if you wanted to. I'll add that to the answer. Either one will work.

Comment: I'm using a tooltip with the `button`. With `data-bind` for `title`, seems that JavaScript doesn't render the tooltip. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure. The tooltip seems to be working the jsFiddle. Does `title="..."` show up properly in the source of your page?

Comment: Yes, the *native* tooltip is working in jsFiddle. As I've said, I'm using a custom tooltip and I have no success with `data-bind`. And yes, the `title` is showing properly in my page.